# Calculating angle to object based on height dimensions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given $h_1$ and $h_2$ (left and right height of a square respectively **at a certain perspective**), how can we calculate the angle relative to a square **from that perspective**?

See the following diagrams for clarification:

[image: 1]

^^^ this is the view of the square **from that perspective**

[image: top down view showing angle to find]

^^^ this is a top view showing the angle we are trying to calculate

This is a rather complex task - it's difficult for me to approach it. Is it possible by getting a predetermined angle & ratio of $h_1$ and $h_2$ and using similarities?

**Note**: not sure if it will help but $h_1$ and $h_2$ are both numerical values (pixels)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Is the "visualization" a perspective drawing of the plane in the second view?

Comment: Yep. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is predict the angle of a camera relative to a square based on height measurements of the two sides. The second image shows the angle that I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the eye of the viewer be at $(0, 0, e)$

Let the square have side $a$ and its center be at $(0, 0, -d)$

Let the projection plane be the $xy$ plane, and the plane of the square have a unit normal vector of $N = (\sin t, 0, \cos t)$.  Spanning vectors of the plane of the square are: $(\cos t, 0, -\sin t)$  and $(0, 1, 0)$.

---

Top Corners of the square:

Top Left corner at: $(0, 0, -d) + (a/2) ( - \cos t, 1, \sin t )$

Top Right corner at: $(0, 0, -d) + (a/2) ( \cos t , 1, -\sin t )$

---

Ray from eye to top left corner is:

$r = (0, 0, e) + s ( (0, 0, -d - e) + (a/2) ( - \cos t, 1, \sin t ) )$

at $z = 0$:

$s = \dfrac{- e}{  - d - e + (a/2) \sin t } = \dfrac{e}{d + e - (a/2) \sin t} $

In the image, the top left corner has coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$ with

$x_1 = - \dfrac{(ae/2) \cos t}{  d + e - (a/2) \sin t }$

$y_1 = \dfrac{a e/2 } {d + e  - (a/2) \sin t }$

Similarly, in the image, the top right corner has coordinates $(x_2, y_2)$ with

$x_2 = \dfrac{a e / 2 \cos t}{  d + e + (a/2) \sin t }$

$y_2 = \dfrac{a e / 2}{ d + e + (a/2) \sin t }$

If follows that

$- x_1 / y_1 =  \cos t  =  x_2 / y_2 $

Hence,

$x_1 = -\cos t \ y_1$

$x_2 = \cos t \ y_2$

The horizontal width of the image (the distance between the two vertical lines) is

$ W = x_2 - x_1 = \cos t (y_2 + y_1 ) $

But $y_1 = \dfrac{h_1}{2} $ and $y_2 = \dfrac{h_2}{2} $

Hence,

$\cos t = \dfrac{ W }{\overline{h}}$

where $\overline{h} = \dfrac{1}{2} ( h_1 + h_2 ) $

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll try it out later. Thank you!